# Converting arrays in stl like copy

Tags: c++, stl, vector, copy

It's time for another 'how do i do this in c++ without loosing my grip'-question!

This time:

Considering the following code taken from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/):

```
template<class InputIterator, class OutputIterator>
  OutputIterator copy ( InputIterator first, InputIterator last, OutputIterator result )
{
  while (first!=last) *result++ = *first++;
  return result;
}
```

Is there a way to cast `*first` to the type of `*result`?

In other words: is there a way to determine (at compiletime) the type of result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes, the type of `*result` is ('cause the type of `result` is `OutputIterator` )

```
typename std::iterator_traits<OutputIterator>::value_type
```

of course, if OutputIterator is a pointer or a correctly written STL-compatible iterator. Otherwise, no, I think there is no way.
In the upcoming C++0x, it would be much easier, that is,

```
decltype(*result)
```

HTH,

Armen

Comment: This only answers half the question (how to get the value type of the output iterator, but not how to make `copy` perform the cast on every element

Comment: great!

that actually saved my day :)

Comment: jalf: I think the first half of the question was a misphrasing of the second part

Comment: @jalf:

yes ... but that part is 90% ... performing the cast is as easy as:

    typedef std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type TType;
    T foo = TType(anyOtherType);

Comment: @Florian: don't forget the 'typename', it is essential, i.e. typedef typename std::iterator_traits..... :)

Comment: hmm... it compiles fine without the typename in VS2005... but i added it just to be sure.

Comment: @Florian: well, that's because microsoft doesn't do two-phase lookup. But the standard requires that in this situation typename be explicitly used

Comment: ah thanks for enlightening me here ... i'm from a java and linux background ... so most of this is completly unknown to me

Answer (score 1):

Not a precise answer to your question, but it sounds like you want don't really want to `std::copy`, you want to `std::transform` your data to another type.  In which case, do something like:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
B convert(A x) { return static_cast<B>(x); }

...

std::transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), convert<float,int>);
```

Comment: and where exactly did you deduce int and float from? The question was, as I understood it, how to retrieve the value type of an iterator in generic code.

Comment: @Armen: It's an example!  Obviously this can be parameterised more generically.  The point of my answer is that you don't need to reinvent the STL...

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the copy routine to use a template to do the casting...

```
template <typename A, typename B>                                               
const A& cast(const A&, const B& b)                                             
{                                                                               
    return *reinterpret_cast<const A*>(&b);                                     
};                                                                              

template <class InputIterator, class OutputIterator>                            
OutputIterator mycopy(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,                    
                      OutputIterator result)                                      
{                                                                               
    for ( ; first != last; ++first, ++result)                                   
        *result = cast(*result, *first);                                        
    return result;                                                              
}
```

That said, Oli's answer's much better if your not specifically looking to learn how to modify copy to handle this....

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.  If OutputIterator is really an
OutputIterator (e.g. an ostream_iterator), then:
    typename std::iterator_traits::value_type
will be void, and in C++0x,
    decltype(*result)
is likely to be OutputIterator.  (So Armen's suggestion doesn't
work in template code.)

And Tony's suggestion involving reinterpret_cast doesn't work
either.  In fact, it will break things that do work (e.g. when
InputIterator is returning int, and OutputIterator wants
double).

The only real answer is Oli's.  Which is logical: what you
really want to do is transform your data, not just copy it.

Comment: 1."and in C++0x, decltype(*result) is likely to be OutputIterator" Why?  "2.If OutputIterator is really an OutputIterator (e.g. an ostream_iterator), then...". Well, technically speaking you are right, but one can specialize the iterator_traits for output_iterator, can't he?

Comment: Although Oli's answer doesn't cover how he's going to deduce what type to convert to either. As to specializing `iterator_traits`, isn't it technically illegal (only specializations in std namespace allowed for *user-defined* types)? - But you could create your own iterator traits, and specialize *that* for `ostream_iterator`.

Comment: You aren't allowed to specialize anything in std::, except if
the specialization involves one of your classes.  How do you
know that the implementation hasn't already specialized
iterator_traits for ostream_iterator, for some particular
reasons of its own?